# Authentication with Devise in rails_api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have used devise a couple of time and it's been very useful and time saving but in those applications i was using `erb templates` . Now i'm making a rails api using `rails_api` and it's making trouble to simple sign up . for sign_up when i make a **postman call** like `localhost:3000/users?user[email]=abc@no.co&user[username]=abc&user[password]=12345` (a post call) it show me error

> undefined local variable or method `resource' for for # < #  < Class:0x00000004407780>:0x000000051ad790>

and before that i made some changes then it was showing error for `protect_from_forgery`. Can any one help me out of this problem :( and suggest either there is a better way to use devise or anything else . Thanks in advance

Comment: `undefined local variable or method 'resource' for` what? Can you add the full error?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko kindly have a look , i updated it

Answer (score 0):

devise will not work with rails_api by default
you should try [simple_token_authentication](https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication) or [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth)

Comment: but it's throwing error like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35013635/filter-chain-halted-as-validate-sign-up-params-rendered-or-redirected-devise