# Filter chain halted as :validate_sign_up_params rendered or redirected - devise_token_auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, postman, rails-api

I'm working on a ruby on rails API using **[devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#mounting-routes)** as authentication , and i'm getting this error everytime i'm making a API call from ***postman google chrom*** extension .below are my settings

Gemfile

```
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'devise_token_auth'
gem 'byebug'
gem 'rack-cors', :require => 'rack/cors'
```

routes.rb

```
mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
 include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
    before_action :authenticate_user! , :except=>[:new, :create]
```

**User model:**

```
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
          :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
          :confirmable, :omniauthable
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User

  after_initialize :set_provider #, :set_uid

def set_provider
    byebug
 self[:provider] = "email" if self[:provider].blank?

end


def set_uid
  byebug
  self[:uid] = self[:email] if self[:uid].blank? && self[:email].present?
end
```

and i'm a little worried that why these `byebug` in the `User Model` are not working ! which ,because i think that it's not coming to model user

Comment: removed your cookies from browser.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it was a big blunder in my case . `validate_sign_up_params` error occurs due to wrong parameters , in my case i was sending right parameters but wrapped in user object like `user[name]` , `user[email]` etc . so all i have to do was to unwrap these and make the call like below:

```
localhost:3000/auth?email=abcd@no.co&password=123456789&password_confirmation=123456789
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to compare your project with this [repo](https://github.com/simoneromanelli/api_web_server).
We basically setup the same environment. In particular take a look at this [file](https://github.com/simoneromanelli/api_web_server/blob/master/spec/controllers/restricted_controller_spec.rb) to see how an authenticate request work.